# A formula for $\pi$

Tags: calculus, power-series

I discovered in an exercise that $$\boxed{\pi=12\int_{0}^{2-\sqrt3}\frac{dt}{1+t^2}}$$since $\frac{\pi}{12}=\arctan( 2-\sqrt3)$, what we were made to demonstrate with formulas with half angles.

I tried the following

$$\forall |t|<1, \frac{1}{1+t^2}=1-t^2+t^4-t^6+...$$So $$\pi\approx12\left( \alpha-\frac{\alpha^3}{3}+\frac{\alpha^5}{5} \right)\approx 3.1418$$with $\alpha=2-\sqrt3$

Since it's an alternating series, we get $$|\pi-12(\alpha+...+(-1)^n\frac{\alpha^{2n+1}}{2n+1}|\leq \frac {12}{2n+3}\frac{3^{2n+3}}{10^{2n+3}}$$since $\alpha<0.3$

For example,

- with $n=5$, $$3.1415925<\pi<3.1415928$$
- with $n=8$, $$\frac{88081345207880}{51051} - \frac{84756313789596 \sqrt3}{85085}= 3.141592653...$$

---

As far as I can judge, one advantage of this process is that it gives approximations of type $a+b\sqrt3,(a,b)\in \mathbb Q^2$ and thus reduces the approximation of $\pi$ to that of $\sqrt3$.

What are some mathematical arguments for mathematically criticizing what I probably naively call " one advantage"?

Comment: You've rediscovered one of the many ways to approximate $\pi$ via a series. I think that's an interesting enough observation and nice work. I also guess it's not one of the easiest series to use to develop many digits of $\pi$.

Comment: You may be interested by [Machin-like formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machin-like_formula). Wishing you fun!

Comment: What kind of other uses are you looking for? For me, this is a simple consequence of the indefinite integral $\displaystyle\int\dfrac{dx}{1+x^2}=\arctan(x)+C.$ And there are plenty of other indefinite integrals, like $2\displaystyle\int\sqrt{1-x^2} dx=\arcsin(x)+x\sqrt{1-x^2}+C$, with this capability.

Comment: @Bumblebee : What I find interesting about this formula is the close relationship it establishes between $\pi$ and $\sqrt3$. I'm in the process of learning about field extensions, for example something interesting about $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 3)$. By the way, I'm doing the calculations with wolfram alpha and maybe something to say about the results displayed as the pi approximations are obtained

Comment: With wolfram alpha, $n=8$ in my **edit**, we obtain $\frac{88081345207880}{51051} - \frac{84756313789596 \sqrt3}{85085}= 3.141592653....$

Comment: I'm puzzled by the upper limit of $2-\sqrt{3}$, why not simply $\displaystyle \int_0^1\frac{dx}{1+x^2}=\frac{\pi}{4}$

Comment: $\forall |t|\color{red}{<1}, \frac{1}{1+t^2}=1-t^2+t^4-t^6+...$

Comment: My favorite way is still the iteration $x_1=3$ , $x_{n+1}=x_n+\sin(x_n)$ , very quickly indeed converging to $\pi$

Comment: @StéphaneJaouen Integration of the series over $(0,1)$ is still allowed and the result is the so-called [Leibniz series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_%CF%80).